# protege 3.5 set java path windows

Tags: java, protege

when trying to run/reinstall protege 3.5 it fails because it uses the wrong java path:  it's trying to run c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\bin\java.exe,  in reality the correct javapath is c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe but I don't know where protege gets this from?  I'm using the web installer (launchanywhere).

I've looked at the environment variables and there's nothing that mentions javapath\bin... however ...\java\javapath; is part of the path variable, how can I change protege and its installer to acknowledge this java path?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried using  install_protege_3.5.exe LAX_VM "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\bin\java.exe" as suggested here: http://rivix.com/Tech_Tips/tech_tip_win3.php for other launchanywhere package.

but the installer seem to ignore my parameters,  I then proceeded to download the full version including the vm, I previously had downloaded only protege.

With the full version (e.g. including the vm) I was able to launch the installer to choose my preferred vm.  It's all working now, thanks